# Selecionar dois campos de hora onde um deles passa da meia-noite

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho duas tabelas com o seguinte esquema:

```
data       | hora ini   | hora fim
-----------|------------|---------
16/08/2016 | 1115       | 1319
16/08/2016 | 1320       | 1419
16/08/2016 | 1420       | 90
```

Sendo que na segunda tabela, ela já tem os registros inseridos de meia em meia hora, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
data       | hora 
-----------|-------
16/08/2016 | 1380
16/08/2016 | 1410
17/08/2016 | 0       
17/08/2016 | 30       
17/08/2016 | 60  
17/08/2016 | 90
17/08/2016 | 120
```

O que eu preciso é que quando eu for atualizar um registro da segunda tabela, por exemplo o registro da meia noite, ele faça uma busca se não há nenhum registro na primeira tabela que "passe entre 00:00 e 00:30". Ou seja, se existir um período apontado na primeira tabela que seja das 22:00 até 01:00, ele deve aparecer neste select.

Eu consigo montar um BETWEEN para retornar os registros, porém, quando ele passa da meia noite ele buga pois a hora final acaba sendo menor que a inicial.

Comment: Se a data 2 for maior, BETWEEN( d1, d2 ) se a data 2 for menor, NOT BETWEEN( d2, d1 )

Comment: Não funciona desta forma. Acredito que minha solução tenha ficado assim: http://prntscr.com/c7gxs0

Comment: a solução não passa por buscar data&hora ? Algo como ...        data between to_date('16/08/2016 23:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') and to_date('1708/2016 00:30','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')

Comment: não, amigo, pois a data dentro od parâmetro to_date vem de um mesmo campo, ou seja, não são diferentes mas iguais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui fazer isto funcionar com o seguinte query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
-- This inline view gets everything in your table, plus the start_datetime and end_datetime as calculated from your various fields.
SELECT your_table.*, start_date + ( start_time / 1440 ) start_datetime, start_date + case when end_time < start_time then end_time + 1440 else end_time end end_datetime FROM your_table
) 
WHERE start_datetime between ... whatever date range you want ...
AND end_datetime between ... whatever date range you want ...
```

Desta forma, consegui fazer todos os selects que eu precisava.